# MS Access query memo fields being cut off

Tags: sql, ms-access, text, truncate, memo

I have an MS Access table that uses a memo field for longer text entries.

I am using a query to pull information from that table + joined with some others in order to create a recordset to iterate over / send emails from.

However the memo field is being cut off / truncated down to 255 characters despite the fact it's a memo field and not a text field. Is it being downcasted somehow? Is there a way to "force" it to be memo in the query?

Doing some research I see that sometimes the issue is the use of "groupby" or "distinct" in the query but I don't see how you can avoid using that when pulling fields into a query? How are you supposed to include memo fields in a query?

Comment: Your query uses GROUP BY or DISTINCT? Edit question to show code and/or SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using GROUP BY or DISTINCT in your query. If you replace your memo column with FIRST([memo column]) it may help.

Allen Browne has some really good Access tips.
http://allenbrowne.com/bug-18.html